# JSP: Multiple Annotations at this line

Tags: jsp, syntax, annotations

Ecplise show me a SyntaxError but i don´t understand the reason.

The Code:

```
  ...
  <c:set var="moduleIncPage" value="${moduleIncPage}" scope="request"></c:set> 
  ...
  <c:if test="${not empty model.document.module}">
    <jsp:include page="<%=moduleIncPage %>" flush="true" />
   </c:if>
  ...
```

The "Error" is shown at the "m" on <%=moduleIncPage &>:

```
  Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
 MethodInvocation
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
- Syntax error, insert ")" to complete
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put tags inside a tag attribute, this line is not valid (not XHTML compliant) :

```
<jsp:include page="<%=moduleIncPage %>" flush="true" />
```

You should do it like that instead :

```
<jsp:include page="${moduleIncPage}" flush="true" />
```

Look at the code highlight, you see already the error!